# Change icon of running firefox profile

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, icons

I'm using Win7 but looking for a cross os solution, but this isnt even working in my Win7. I'm trying to change the icon of just the current profile. So what i did was:

1. I created shortcut of firefox.exe and moved it to my documents
2. right click on this shortcut and then changed icon
3. but in firefox the taskbar shows normal firefox icon and so does the top left icon (see attached image plz)

How can I change this icon?

Thanks

[image]

Here's another topic i made on ask.m.o trying to ask the same thing: https://ask.mozilla.org/question/725/custom-icon-per-profile/

Comment: This topic got 1000+ views I just got notified. I resolved this on Windows, Mac, and almost on Linux. If anyone wants help doing the same definitely post a message here and I'll show it to you. If you can help on the Linux part too that would be awesome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## As of Firefox 57, this is not possible from an extension.

WebExtensions do not permit the window icon to be changed from an extension.

## Prior to Firefox 57 (or non-release versions w/ legacy add-ons)

The combination of the title of your question and the text of your question make it unclear what you desire to accomplish.

If your goal is to *dynamically* change the window icon of a currently running Firefox process then you will need to follow something along the lines of the second or third method listed in nmaier's answer.

If you goal is to *always* have a different, static icon used for the primary Firefox windows for a specific profile, that is quite easy.

You will need icon files of the appropriate format for each architecture for which you desire this to work.

The following assumes Windows, it is easily expanded to other architectures by including an icon file with the same name, but appropriate file extension and format.

Create a simple *overlay*, *extracted* extension. You will need a minimum of 2 files:

1. <extension-dir>instal.rdf
2. <extension-dir>\chrome\icons\default\main-window.ico

Example, fully functional, install.rdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
    <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
        <em:id>window-icon-change@nowhere.foo</em:id>
        <em:version>1.0.0</em:version>
        <em:name>Window icon change</em:name>
        <em:description>Change the Firefox main window icon.</em:description>
        <em:creator>Makyen</em:creator>
        <em:unpack>true</em:unpack>
        <em:targetApplication>
            <Description>
                <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>3.0a1</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>43.0a1</em:maxVersion>
            </Description>
        </em:targetApplication>
    </Description>
</RDF>
```

NOTE: The "<extension-dir>\chrome\icons\default\" directory is different than the one in the response by nmaier. In that answer the "icons" and "default" directories reversed and will be non-functional.

You will probably want an additional file:
<extension-dir>chrome.manifest
The chrome.manifest file is not required. However, not having it may result in a single line being printed to the error/browser console (if you even have that open). If the chrome.manifest file exists, even if zero length, there will be no complaint in the console that the file could not be read.

Install the extension. The easy way to do this is to create a zip file with those three files; then change the file extension to .xpi; then drag and drop it onto a Firefox window running the profile in which you desire it to be installed.

You can expand this to include icons for whatever sub-windows you desire.  You will need to determine the ID for each sub-window. The icon file name is just the window ID with the appropriate extension for an icon in the architectures you desire. "main-window" is just the ID for the main Firefox browser window.

Creating an extension to test this took less than 5 minutes.  You should find it reasonably easy to accomplish.

This assumes that there is not a custom main-window icon located at (Windows, default install location):
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\chrome\icons\default
as that directory is for all profiles and is searched first.

This will not work if the extension is either restartless or extractionless.

You can find a brief amount of information [about window icons on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Window_icons). nmaier mentions the docs talking about bundles. When talking about Mozilla add-ons, a [bundle is your add-on package.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Bundles)

The icon file(s) will be at (Windows):
<profile dir>\extensions\<extension-dir>\chrome\icons\default*
Once the extension is installed, you can change it/them manually without re-installing, if desired.

#### Add-ons created to solve this

Based on the discussion in the comments, I created a Firefox Add-on to allow setting the window icons for the profile.  It is much expanded upon the 5 minute add-on mentioned in the comments. The addition is entirely in a UI for the options dialog for selecting the icon to use and assigning it to the various different windows Firefox opens. You can get it from Mozilla Add-ons under [**Change Profile's Window Icons**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/change-window-icons/). Unfortunately, it's **not possible** for that add-on to function as of Firefox 48 which requires add-ons to be signed. To dynamically change the icon requires changing files which must be signed. Thus it's not possible to dynamically change the icon with add-on signing required.

Instead I created a few add-ons which statically change the window icon. [You can find them on AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=change%20profile%27s%20window%20icons&platform=WINNT&appver=56.0.2).

Comment: I admit my question was unclear on the dynamic or not part. I like your answer. Can you please link an example of the 5 minute add-on that uses this. Thanks. I'm going to accept this solution too.

Comment: Yep, nice write-up on my point 1. However, like I stated, you'll run into trouble with this when the Firefox distribution provides default icons for a window type, which some *nix distributions do (or used to do?). Then you cannot provide another icon via an extension. @Noitidart, BTW you cannot actually "accept this solution too", only switch the accepted answer, which is what you did. ;)

Comment: @nmaier Ah bah. I gave you like a thousand points anyways, I'm going to try to lure this guy in as a SO answerer who has good spelling and  writes out posts like you, by giving him points. :P (even though I used your method from that `SetClassLongPtr` example which is better than your below method :P )

Comment: @Noitidart I would be happy to provide a link to such an extension.  However, that immediately brings up the question: What icon do you desire included? If I am providing a link including the icon, it needs to have an appropriate license for me to do so (which is why I don't just link with what I tested).

Comment: Thanks man. Can you say for educational purposes and would that make things ok? lol if not can you please ues this icon here: [IconArchive :: Blue Bits Icons by Icojam - Puzzle](http://www.iconarchive.com/show/blue-bits-icons-by-icojam/module-puzzle-icon.html) [\[Download ICO\]](http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i65516/icojam/blue-bits/module-puzzle.ico)

Comment: You should be able to get it from http://www.mediafire.com/download/7m2gnqwd5ef644h/window-icon-change@nowhere.foo.xpi

Comment: I did change the name and description in the install.rdf from what I had provided above.  I have now updated that also.  The changes are just cosmetic. Once downloaded, you should be able to drag-and-drop the window-icon-change@nowhere.foo.xpi file onto a Firefox window running the profile you desire to change. Doing so worked fine for me. A restart of Firefox will be required. You can easily change the icon by just replacing the <profile dir>\extensions\window-icon-change@nowhere.foo\chrome\icons\defaultmain-window.ico file. Please keep me informed if you have any problems.

Comment: I added a link in the answer to an enhanced version of the extension begun in these comments.  The extension is [Change Profile's Window Icons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/change-window-icons/) at Mozilla Add-ons.

Comment: Oh man I missed that demo addon you uploaded!! Thanks I'm going to test it tomorrow on linux and mac :) thanks man! You gotta @ my name so i can see these comments please :P otherwise i get no notification :(

Comment: I get this “this addon could not be installed, because it appears to be corrupt”, when I drag the file into firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are some ways that spring to mind, but all with their own issues:

1. Using [*Window Icons*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Window_icons) provided by an add-on you install into the profile (the docs talk about bundles, but add-on can also use this technique). The add-on must be `em:unpack` and have the icon(s) in `chrome/default/icons` exactly. It is possible that the Firefox in question has an own set of icons bundled in the `$appdir/chrome/default/icons`, in particular on `*nix` and since [they are checked first](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/99137ca57770/toolkit/xre/nsXREDirProvider.cpp#l704), they will be used instead of the add-on provided add-ons. So while this approach works for custom add-on windows, it might not for built-in ones.
2. Copy and patch Firefox itself, aka. the sledgehammer approach. Different for each platform (e.g. under Windows you'd have to swap out the icon resource of the `firefox.exe`).
3. Create a tool that will switch out the icons of a running window. There is no code to do so in Firefox that would be accessible from javascript, so you need to go binary and platform-specific, e.g. [`WM_SETICON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows.

*Edit 1*:
Actually, thinking more about it, I'd install an add-on with some platform-specific js-ctypes code that would then switch out the icons, e.g. the already mentioned `WM_SETICON` on Windows.

Usually you'll need a window handle for the platform APIs, which Firefox refuses to provide to JS. But as a workaround for that:

1. Store the window title.
2. Set the window title to a new `uuid`.
3. Call a platform API to find the new `uuid` titled window handle (`FindWindow` on Windows). [mintrayr](https://github.com/nmaier/mintrayr) uses this scheme for Windows/Gnome(GTK/GDK), also not in js-ctypes.
4. Restore the window title.
5. Load/transform the icon file to something the platform supports (`HICON` on windows). I once had a patch somewhere on bugzilla that enabled loading of arbitrary images as window icons FWIW, but let it slide. Should be still somewhere and could give pointers.
6. Switch the icon using the obtained handle. E.g. Sending two `WM_SETICON` for small/big icon on Windows.

*Edit 2*
Turns out `nsIBaseWindow` exposes a `nativeHandle` these days, as I learned from your other question. so the window-title–hack isn't needed any longer. However, `nativeHandle` might be an 64-bit pointer, which isn't really supported in JS land without some trickery... Better not `parseInt` it... Also js numbers are floats.

`ctypes.voidptr_t(ctypes.UInt64(nativeHandle))` should work, though.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for this detail man i thought it was hopeless as no one gave me replies else where. Can you please elaborate on #2 please. I think that's a good idea because i need to copy and give it a `-P -profileName` so if user pins it to taskbar then closes FF then launches again from that pin it will launch into right profile.

Comment: Well, you rewrite the binary, e.g. modify bits and bytes in `firefox.exe` or whatever a platform uses. There are various tools that let you edit icon resources in `exe` and similar tools for non-Windows platforms. Please note that on Windows binary is Authenticode-signed, so you might also want to remove the signature after patching the binary.

Comment: Ohhh yikes this is not possible for my restartless addon huh? I'm trying to plug into profilist, please see this image: https://github.com/evacchi/firefox-custom-badge/issues/1

Comment: Also in #1 what is the way to do it for mac os?

Comment: Re #1 mac: OS X does not actually have window icons, just `.app` icons, which you cannot change.

Comment: Wow man thanks so much man your answers are sooooo detailed you spend so much time on them you deserve like 5 points each question. I think I'll try that ctypes approach you mentioned thanks man!

Comment: Hey man here's my work *Re #3* [GitHub - Gist :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-ChangeWindowIcon.js - Rev1](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/33b6d28ebf4ff5ebdff6). It's got some issues I need help with though, I'll make a separate topic for that.

Comment: Left a few comments on your gist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55030/discussion-between-noitidart-and-nmaier).

Comment: Thanks man for that edit. If it's `UInt64` can't I just set the ctypes paramter to that. So what I did was: `var SendMessage = user32.declare('SendMessageW', ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.uintptr_t, ctypes.uint64_t,` then `var targetWindow_handle = nativeHandle;` I got the error: `Exception: expected type uint64_t, got "0x1070140"`

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X, this Firefox plugin will do just that: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fosx-label/. Also on GitHub: https://github.com/jf/fosx-label. Thanks to Noitidart for pointing out this very useful plugin.

Tested on Yosemite 10.10.5 and it works perfectly!

Comment: Excellent job man!! If you are available and have time, you should hook up this method: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/6e39b7a0b2c3419a1165 i am implementing a feature like that with Profilist, the complex part was making the icns (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXV7N74IXYc and https://github.com/Noitidart/Icon-Container-Generator ), but for simplicity you can just use a single png.

Comment: The plugin doesn't seem to work with the latest version of FireFox (version 54, 2017).  Is there another technique?